# Files on network share say they are open by [Disconnected]

Tags: windows-server-2016, network-share

I have a Windows Server 2016 with network shared drives. All users from the company can access files on that server.

Sometimes there are files that cannot be opened, deleted, or moved. The program with which the user tries to open one of the problematic files will just hang. Looking in compmgmt.msc, I can see that those files say they are accessed by [Disconnected]. These files can stay like that for days, usually until the server is rebooted.

My question is: what can lead to files saying they are accessed by [Disconnected]? Understanding this will help me find what causes theses files to become unmodifiable.